# How to select rows in database by extracting date from a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Example date today: 2018-04-05

and I have a mysql database like this:

```
     date_time      |    name
2018-04-05 00:00:00 |    cust1
2018-04-05 00:00:00 |    cust2
2017-01-01 00:00:00 |    cust3
2016-01-01 00:00:00 |    cust4
```

how do I get the names by using date_time and using curdate() function

Comment: You can use Convert(date, date_time)

Comment: What is wrong with `date_time = curdate()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff will it work even though there is time on it?

Comment: @nyelnyelnyelnyelnyel . . . No, but in your sample data, all the values have zero times.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the data with date_time = 04/04/2018;

```
select * 
from yourTable
where date(date_time) = CURRENT_DATE()
```